# JQ - Select JSON subarray by value then update by index

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to process some JSON output and modify a value but struggling to get anywhere.

I have no control over the source data, which looks like this:

```
[
    [
        "dave",
        "likes",
        "rabbits"
    ],
    [
        "brian",
        "likes",
        "fish"
    ]
]
```

In pseudo code, I need to:

- Select the subarray with value "brian" at index 0
- Change the value at index [2] in the selected array to "cats"
- Return the complete modified array

I've managed to use map and select to get the subarray I want (`jq -r -c 'map(select(.[]=="brian"))`), but not build that into anything more useful...

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the required value by specifying the array indices and using the `|=` update select construct

```
map(select(.[0] == "brian")[2] |= "cats" )
```

This also populates `[2]` with `"cats"` even if previously there was no value at the specific index.

Of course it goes without saying, the indices could be dynamically arrived at as well

```
map(select(any(.[]; . == "brian"))[2] |= "cats")
```